# Ignore these two numbers (starts with 127 or 0) in the first octet of the ip address through python regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-2.7, ip-address

I have a list of IP's stored in a text file along with some other data from which I am trying to grep only the valid IP's. Here, I have some IP's like 0.0.0.0 and localhost IP's (starts with 127...) which I am trying to eliminate using regex.
Here is the regex pattern I came up with that filters 0.0.0.0 IP's but couldn't effectively remove the 127..* IP's.

```
import re
with open("data","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        test = re.search(r'(?!0|127)\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}', line)
        if test:
            print(test.group(0))
```

The IP's are in the text file like this:

```
127.3.65.7
alkjgfbvui vluiybr vk ru r127.0.0.1fal;iufnaw  waoun
12.0.1.5
mjhgvjg0.0.0.0kjuycuj
0.0.0.0
0.0.0.0
gare bloing r pgnao wyin212.2.174.64
207.71.31.224
awuie nvp; vwa rv;awiu n ;lkirjght94.206.93.104ta;wourit mrt'
172.20.128.1
172.20.164.207
172.20.164.203
172.20.164.209
1.8.0.144
```

I am getting the following output where you can see IP's that starts with 127 is also printed by just removing the first digit '1'

```
27.3.65.7
27.0.0.1
12.0.1.5
212.2.174.64
207.71.31.224
94.206.93.104
172.20.128.1
172.20.164.207
172.20.164.203
172.20.164.209
1.8.0.144
```

Comment: Alternatively, just capture all IP(v4)s and then compare with the ones to exclude.. also, what about `127.0.0.42`?

Comment: @user2864740 Edited the question All IP's in localhost range has to be eliminated. The thing is, I am originally reading from 1000's of files and so almost 5000 IP's I am storing in a csv file. If you compare the regex match for all those IP's, it's kind of time complex.

Comment: 5000 is a tiny number ~ 0 time to computer for such a fast operation. The performance bottleneck, if any, is probably elsewhere, like the actual IO read. Also, without testing and measuring of *actual* performance, I have little reason to believe that a regex [with a look behind] is any/relevantly faster than a regex + guard. P.S. My not-new computer has 4 cores, all of which 'tick' at up to 3.4 BILLION times a second.

Comment: @user2864740 Yes. Considering the computing power, 5000 is small number. But what if those 1000 files I parse through are large (in hundreds of MB's) to scrape the IP's? I have files of type html, .pp, json, xml, Readme.md, etc. I need something efficient. Out of 5000 IP's only approx 300 IP's are in 127... rangne. For that, I don't want to compare for other 4000's of IP's

Comment: Irrelevant to this 'performance' issue. You've spent more time writing the last comment then tens of (possibly even tens of hundreds of) thousands of such checks. Also, chances of it being *a/the* performance issue in the scheme of the program: about 0. There is no point trying to 'optimize' without actual performance data, or even relevant experience, and cases supporting such effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Regex: `(?<!\d)(?!0|127)\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6vkkqm/1/)

Explanation:

Add a negative look behind for \d to eliminate matches starting with 27

Comment: I tried yours out and saw that my answer was wrong. Here's a demo of yours: https://regex101.com/r/CMGOHz/3

Comment: @Zev, the Demo text in my answer was supposed to be the link to regex101. somehow I missed it. I have edited to update the demo link. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks @Matt.G for the answer